# How to extract/save a camera's lookAt vector in three.js?

Tags: three.js

In Three.js, is it possible to save the resulting vector when calling `lookAt()`?  I'd like to hold onto it for re-pointing the camera later, as a sort of reset.

I looked at the code for `lookAt()` and saw various matrix and quaternion manipulations but am unable to figure how to pull the final vector out of it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to reset the camera's orientation, just remember the `camera.rotation` vector, and then do something like this:

```
camera.rotation.copy( myRotationVector );
```

For info on computing the "lookAt" vector, you can refer to [three.js set and read camera look vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696963/three-js-set-and-read-camera-look-vector/).