# Three.js Get Camera lookAt Vector

Tags: three.js

I'm looking to translate the camera along its lookAt vector.  Once I have this vector, I can do scalar translation along it, use that point to move the camera position in global coordinates and re-render.  The trick is getting the arbitrary lookAt vector?  I've looked at several other questions and solutions but they don't seem to work for me.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696963/three-js-set-and-read-camera-look-vector/. Also, is `camera.translateZ( -1 )` what you mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't get the `lookAtVector` from the camera itself, you can however create a new vector and apply the camera rotation to that.

```
var lookAtVector = new THREE.Vector3(0,0, -1);
lookAtVector.applyQuaternion(camera.quaternion);
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696963/three-js-set-and-read-camera-look-vector/15697227#15697227

Comment: so what exactly is the difference? :)

Comment: The difference was the negative lookup vector, the answer has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

The first choice should be `cam.translateZ();`

There is a second option as well. You can extract the lookAt vector from the `matrix` property of the camera object. You just need to take the elements corresponding to the local z-axis.

```
var lookAtVector = new THREE.Vector3(cam.matrix[8], cam.matrix[9], cam.matrix[10]);
```