# How can I get the normalized vector of the direction an object3D is facing?

Tags: rotation, three.js, quaternions

I have an object in my scene and want to get the normalized vector that represents the direction it is facing.  In Unity, the equivalent is transform.forward.  How can I access this in THREE.js?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how to determine the direction vector in which an object is facing, or "looking":

By default, an object is considered to be looking up its internal positive z-axis, so create a vector pointing in the direction of the positive z-axis:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );
```

Now, apply the same rotation to the vector that is applied to the object:

```
vector.applyQuaternion( object.quaternion );
```

The resulting vector will be pointing in the direction that the object is facing -- *as long as the object has no transformed parent objects*.

If the object has a parent that has a transform applied, then instead of using `object.quaternion`, you need to compute the object's "world quaternion", and use that instead. You do that like so:

```
var position = new THREE.Vector3();
var scale = new THREE.Vector3();
var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );

. . .

object.updateMatrixWorld(); // the renderer does this for you each render loop, so you may not have to

object.matrixWorld.decompose( position, quaternion, scale );

vector.applyQuaternion( quaternion );
```

If the "object" is a camera, then see this answer: [three.js set and read camera look vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696963/three-js-set-and-read-camera-look-vector/15697227#15697227).

three.js r.68