# What is required to convert threejs perspective camera to orthographic

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, perspective, orthographic

I have some code that converts a perspective camera to an orthographic camera. The problem is that when I make the conversion, the model becomes very tiny and hard to see.

I have calculated the zoom factor for the orthographic camera, based on the distance and the FOV. Are there any other properties that I need to set on the orthographic camera (e.g. clipping plane, etc..)?

I believe the position remains the same. I'm not sure what else I need to calculate.

```
    fieldOfView = viewInfo.fov;
var getCameraPosition = function() {
    return viewer._viewport._implementation.getCamera()._nativeCamera.position;
};

// Calculate the delta position between the camera and the object
var getPositionDelta = function(position1, position2) {
    return {
        x: position1.x - position2.x,
        y: position1.y - position2.y,
        z: position1.z - position2.z
    }
};

var getDistance = function(positionDelta, cameraDirection) {
    return dot(positionDelta, cameraDirection);
};

distance = getDistance(positionDelta, cameraDirection),
var depth = distance;

var viewportWidth = view.getDomRef().getBoundingClientRect().width;
var viewportHeight = view.getDomRef().getBoundingClientRect().height;
var aspect = viewportWidth / viewportHeight;

var height_ortho = depth * 2 * Math.atan( fieldOfView * (Math.PI/180) / 2 )
var width_ortho  = height_ortho * aspect;

var near = viewInfo.near, far = viewInfo.far;
var newCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    width_ortho  / -2, width_ortho   /  2,
    height_ortho /  2, height_ortho  / -2,
    near, far );


newCamera.position.copy( viewInfo.position );
var sCamera = new vk.threejs.OrthographicCamera(); //framework creatio of threejs cam

sCamera.setZoomFactor(orthoZoomFactor);
sCamera.setCameraRef(newCamera);
view.getViewport().setCamera(sCamera);
```

I also tried setting the same camera properties (e.g. clipping planes etc) of the perspective for the orthographic and I still had the same problem.

I guess I am missing some property or calculation required to put the object in the same position as when it was in perspective camera view.

Comment: Please don't deface or degrade your question.

Comment: sorry, please check edit. wasn't intentional

Comment: Twice defaced = intentional. Moderators notified to lock this question and prevent further defacement.

Answer (score 8):

Let's assume you have a perspective view with a given vertical field of view angle `fov_y` (in degrees) and you know the size of the viewport `width` and  `height`. Furthermore, you have the `near` and `far` plane. These are the values which you use to setup the [`THREE.PerspectiveCamera`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/cameras/PerspectiveCamera):

```
perspCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( fov_y, width / height, near, far );
```

Also, you know the position of the object and the position of the camera. An object doesn't have only a single position, but you have to choose a representative position for its depth.

First you have to calculate the `depth` of the object.

```
var v3_object = .... // THREE.Vector3 : positon of the object
var v3_camera = perspCamera.position;

var line_of_sight = new THREE.Vector3();
perspCamera.getWorldDirection( line_of_sight );

var v3_distance = v3_object.clone().sub( v3_camera );
depth = v3_distance.dot( line_of_sight );
```

Then you have to calculate the "size" of the rectangle which is projected to the viewport at the `depth`:

[image]

```
aspect = width / height;

height_ortho = depth * 2 * Math.atan( fov_y*(Math.PI/180) / 2 )
width_ortho  = height_ortho * aspect;
```

With these values the [`THREE.OrthographicCamera`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/cameras/OrthographicCamera) can be setup like this:

```
var orthoCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    width_ortho  / -2, width_ortho   /  2,
    height_ortho /  2, height_ortho  / -2,
    near, far );
orthoCamera.position.copy( perspCamera.position );
```

---

The positon and direction of the perspective camera can be committed to the orthographic camera like this:

```
orthoCamera.position.copy( perspCamera.position );
orthoCamera.quaternion.copy( perspCamera.quaternion );
```

See also stackoverflow question [Three.js - Find the current LookAt of a camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957645/three-js-find-the-current-lookat-of-a-camera)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried this but my model moves back. the zoom is very far. am i missing something?

Comment: If i rotate my model when in perspective view and switch back to orthographic view, my model disappears.

Comment: not sure how to. can you please share code to update position and lookAt. thanks

Comment: Thanks. is the lookAt position the same for perspective and ortho? will it always be 0,0,-1?

Comment: @sarah Yes, see [Three.js - Find the current LookAt of a camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957645/three-js-find-the-current-lookat-of-a-camera)

Comment: thank you this resolves the rotation. but still my model shrinks. please see images in edited question. thanks

Comment: @Rabbid76 Did you test this code? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905929/three-js-2xmeshes-using-same-vector-as-position/26916159#26916159). Also, just do this: `cam2.quaternion.copy( cam1.quaternion )`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 `orthoCamera.position.copy( perspCamera.position ); orthoCamera.quaternion.copy( perspCamera.quaternion );`

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you, again