# Threejs blending perspective and orthogonal matrix

Tags: typescript, three.js, 3d

I want to have a perspective camera and an orthogonal aligned to each other. They are in the same position, orientation, and the zfar plane is exactly the same.
The problem is that even thought the near, far values are the same I get different z values and the occlusions are wrong. Want I'm missing?

```
const perspective_camera = new PerspectiveCamera(55, canvas.width / canvas.height, near, far);
const half_width = perspective_camera.far * Math.tan(perspective_camera.fov * 0.5 * (Math.PI / 180));
const half_height = half_width / perspective_camera.aspect;
const ortho_camera = new OrthographicCamera(-half_width, half_width, half_height, -half_height, near, far);
// Here one example of the problem in the Z
const aux1 = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
const aux2 = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
console.log(aux1.project(ortho_camera), aux2.project(half_height));
// Object { x: -0.00003130777409465268, y: -0.000001186705638256526, z: -0.999202652754963 }
// Object { x: -0.07660902355148393, y: -0.0029038270148180447, z: 0.9510807024824749 }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. However, the Z-coordiante of a perspective projection is not linear. See [How to render depth linearly in modern OpenGL with gl_FragCoord.z in fragment shader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777913/how-to-render-depth-linearly-in-modern-opengl-with-gl-fragcoord-z-in-fragment-sh)

Comment: See also [Transpose z-position from perspective to orthographic camera in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829113/transpose-z-position-from-perspective-to-orthographic-camera-in-three-js/47053505#47053505) and [What is required to convert threejs perspective camera to orthographic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48758959/what-is-required-to-convert-threejs-perspective-camera-to-orthographic/48760593#48760593) ...

Comment: ... and [How to switch between Perspective and Orthographic cameras keeping size of desired object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187416/how-to-switch-between-perspective-and-orthographic-cameras-keeping-size-of-desir/48188014#48188014)

Comment: Thanks @Rabbid76, what I wanted to do is having two scenes in the same world space, one for the orthogonal camera and the other for the perspective. This way I could have in the same frame orthogonal and perspective objects.
But now I see, thanks to you, that the depth is not linear so I don't think I could blend this two perspectives only with the projection matrix. The solution that you propose with the project and unproject is good, but then the scenes won't be in the same world space.

Comment: *"but then the scenes won't be in the same world space."* - Yes, of course, since the projection matrix projects the scene differently, the scene cannot be the same in neither world space nor view space. Thus, there is no simple solution to your problem. The only possibility I can see is to perform special transformations in the vertex shader. In this case, however, you will have to render the scene with your own special material.

Comment: Yep, well at least now I know why I couldn't do it. Thanks for your answers. 
For the moment I will continue with the `project(perspective).unproject(orthogonal)` solution since I can't migrate all my work to a custom shader. 
If you leave this comments as a solution I can mark your answer as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Z-coordinate of a perspective projection is not linear. See [How to render depth linearly in modern OpenGL with gl_FragCoord.z in fragment shader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777913/how-to-render-depth-linearly-in-modern-opengl-with-gl-fragcoord-z-in-fragment-sh). To compensate for this, you have to calculate a coordinate that, after an orthographic projection, leads to a coordinate that has the same z-component as it would have been transformed with a perspective projection. Basically, you have to project perspective and unproject orthographic. See [Transpose z-position from perspective to orthographic camera in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829113/transpose-z-position-from-perspective-to-orthographic-camera-in-three-js/47053505#47053505). Since the orthographic and perspective projection matrices project the scene differently, the coordinates can unfortunately not be the same neither in world space nor in view space. Thus, there is no simple solution to your problem. The only possibility I can see is to perform special transformations in the vertex shader. In this case, however, you will have to render the scene with your own special material.